# How did words like align get a g?

Tags: etymology, orthography

One answer for [Is there an etymological explanation for the silent ‘g’ in “paradigm”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/457805/73636) mentions that words such as 
*align,
apophthegm,
arraign,
assign,
benign,
campaign,
consign,
deign,
design,
diaphragm,
ensign,
feign,
foreign,
hypodigm,
malign,
phlegm,
reign,
resign,
sign,
sovereign,
syntagm*
all have a silent "g" due to the final nasal.

All of the words ending in "-gn" (I'm not concerned with "-gm") ultimately come from Latin, and most have consistently had a "g" since Latin:

- [*assi**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assign): from Old French *assi**gn**er*, from Latin *assi**gn**ō*
- [*beni**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/benign): from Old French *beni**gn**e*, from Latin *beni**gn**us*
- [*consi**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consign): from Old French *consi**gn**er* or directly from Latin *cōnsi**gn**ō*
- [*dei**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deign): from Middle English *dei**gn**en*, from Old French *dei**gn**ier*, from Latin *dī**gn**ō*, *dī**gn**ārī*, from *dī**gn**us*
- [*desi**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/design): from Old French *desi**gn**er*, from Latin *desi**gn**ō*
- [*ensi**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ensign): from Old French *ensei**gn**e*, from Latin *īnsi**gn**ia*
- [*mali**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/malign): from Old French *mali**gn**e*, from Latin *mali**gn**us*
- [*rei**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reign): from Middle English *re**gn**en*, borrowed from Old French *re**gn**er*, from Latin *rē**gn**ō*
- [*resi**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/resign): from Anglo-Norman *resi**gn**er*, Middle French *resi**gn**er*, from Latin *resi**gn**āre*
- [*si**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sign): from Middle English *si**gn**e*, *s**ygn**e*, *s**yn**g*, *seine*, *sine*, *s**yn**e*, from Old English *se**ġn*** and Old French *si**gn**e*, *seing*; both from Latin *si**gn**um*

The "g" in the following words can be easily explained:

- [*campai**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/campaign): from French *campa**gn**e*, from Italian *campa**gn**a*, from Late Latin *campānia*, from Latin *campus*
- [*forei**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foreign): from Middle English *forein*, from Old French *forain*, from Vulgar Latin **forānus*, from Latin *forās*. The spelling altered perhaps by analogy with *soverei**gn***.
- [*soverei**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sovereign): from Old French *soverain*, from Vulgar Latin **superānus*, from Latin *super*. Spelling influenced by folk-etymology association with *rei**gn***

However, the following words get a "g" for no clear reason:

- [*ali**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/align): from Middle English *al**yn**en*, *alinen*, from Middle French *ali**gn**er*, from Old French *ali**gn**ier*, from Latin *lineare*
- [*arrai**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arraign): from Old French *araisnier*, from *a-* +‎ *raison* +‎ *-ier* or from Vulgar Latin **adratiōnāre*
- [*fei**gn***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feign): from Middle English *fe**yn**en*, *feinen*, from Old French *feindre*, from Latin *fingere*

Note that Latin *fingere* is spelt with "ng", not "gn", which then changes to "nd" in Old French before changing to "n" in Middle English and finally "gn" in modern English. I couldn't find the missing etymology.

It looks like perhaps a Middle English spelling with "yn" is a predictor of "gn" in modern English which is why I highlighted all of *si**gn**e*, *s**ygn**e*, and *s**yn**e* as well, but that could be a red herring. How did this final set of words end up with a "g" in them?

Comment: Spellings like "aline" have had some use in modern English also. A related question: [Alignment or alinement?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131067/alignment-or-alinement)

Comment: @sumelic Yes, but it appears that the modern spelling is unrelated to the Middle English spelling, being a simplification or reform rather than a resurrection.

Answer (score 24):

#### In Latin, "gn" was pronounced as two consonants

In Latin, the spelling <gn> represented a sequence of consonants or a heterosyllabic consonant cluster. While we don't know the exact pronunciation for sure, current scholarship leans in favor of the value [ŋn], a velar nasal followed by a coronal nasal.
The history of the similar pronunciation [gn] (a voiced velar plosive followed by a coronal nasal) is a bit unclear, but it certainly was used in later time periods when Latin was no longer spoken as a native language. Even if it was pronounced as [ŋn], many modern phonemic analyses of Latin treat <gn> as /gn/, with an allophonic realization of /g/ as [ŋ] in this environment. Interestingly, the situation with <gm> doesn't seem to have been exactly parallel, as there isn't really any evidence for a pronunciation *[ŋm] existing in Latin. It may be relevant that Classical Latin "gm" mostly arose from relatively late processes of vowel syncope (e.g. *tegmen* < *tegimen*): ancient "gm" clusters seem to have changed in Latin to [mm], with assimilation in both manner and place of the first consonant to the second (e.g. in the word *flamma* "flame").

I wrote a more detailed post about the pronunciation of "gn" in Latin on the [Latin SE site](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/154/9); my main source was W. Sidney Allen's *Vox Latina*.

#### In many Romance languages, Latin "gn" turned into a palatal nasal (a single consonant)

As far as I know, none of the Romance languages retains either [ŋn] or [gn] in inherited/popular vocabulary. (The sequence /gn/ does show up in a number of languages in some learned vocabulary from Latin or Greek; e.g. French *[ignition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/ignition)*.) In Romanian, Latin "gn" became "mn" [mn] (a similar sound change affected Latin "ct", changing it to Romanian "pt" [pt]). In Western and Italian Romance languages, Latin "gn" has generally become a palatal nasal [ɲ] (in standard Italian, the palatal nasal is an "intrinsic geminate", meaning it is always pronounced as a long consonant [ɲː] when it occurs between vowels).

Some of the sources that I've read, such as Allen, say that [ɲ] points towards earlier [gn], via sound changes like [gn] > [ɣn] > [jn] > [ɲ(ː)], but honestly I'm not sure why we couldn't have gotten [ɲ] from [ŋn] via some process like [ŋn] > [ɲn] > [ɲ(ː)]. Anyway, I don't think the details of the sound changes leading up to [ɲ] are particularly relevant to your question. The important point is that Western and Italian Romance languages developed an alternative pronunciation for "gn" that was not the same as the pronunciation that had been used in Latin. Despite the change in pronunciation from Latin, the spelling <gn> was used for this new sound in various Romance languages (although as tchrist's comment mentions, not all: <nh> was also used in some languages, as it still is in modern Portuguese; modern Spanish uses <ñ>; and at one point in French the trigraph <ign> was used to represent [ɲ], a convention that has left a remnant in the modern French spelling <oignon>—see the French SE posts [L'orthographe « ognon » a-t-elle une date de péremption ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26452) and [Oignon/ognon : découpage syllabique ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/17696/6881) for more details).

#### Palatal nasals from sources other than Latin "gn" are nevertheless "unetymologically" (but regularly) written with "gn" in certain Romance languages (e.g. French, Italian)

The [ɲ] sound in Romance languages has other sources than Latin "gn". In your question, you've mentioned some words that exemplify this: French *campagne* and Italian *campagna* come from a Latin word ending in "nia". In words like this, [ɲ] developed from coalescence of /n/ with a following palatal glide, but the digraph <gn> is nevertheless used in Italian and French. This could be considered "unetymological", but it's not irregular: <gn> has become the regular way of representing the palatal nasal, regardless of etymology, in these two languages. Furthermore, Italian uses <gl> and <gli> to represent the palatal lateral, which is often not derived from Latin "gl": e.g. Italian *foglio* [ˈfɔʎːo] "sheet" comes from Latin *folium.*

The same development explains the <gn> in French *ligne* "line" from Latin *linea* (the "e" in the Latin form turned into a palatal glide, which then coalesced with the preceding nasal to form [ɲ]). The English word *align* is related to French *ligne.*

Another historical French sound change got rid of [ɲ] when it came before another consonant, replacing it with [n] (along with a palatal offglide on the preceding vowel). This is why the infinitive form *feindre* has "n" instead of "gn". The "d" here arose by epenthesis of *-nr-* to *-ndr-*. But the present participle stem *feign-* was not affected by either of these sound changes, because the sound [ɲ] here came before a vowel. The development of Latin /ng/ to French [ɲ] in certain contexts is a regular sound change, and the corresponding spelling change to <gn> is also expected, not irregular. I wrote an answer to a related question on Linguistics SE: [How did OF. peindre derive from L. pingere, with a “-ng-” > “-nd-” change?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4235)

#### "arraign": unlike the other words mentioned, it doesn't seem to have come from a Romance word with a palatal nasal

The word *arraign* is the only example you gave where it seems impossible to explain the use of <gn> in terms of influence from the spelling of the French etymon. The OED says it comes from "Anglo-Norman *arainer, areiner, arener,* Old French *arais-, areis-, aresnier* < Latin *adratiōnāre*". Although some French words now spelled with <ni> seem to have had old variants with <gn> (e.g. the OED says <magnioc> existed as a  17th-century French form of *manioc*), I haven't found any evidence that this is the case for *araisnier.* So the use of <gn> in the spelling of this word does seem to have originated in English, by analogy with the spelling of other words.

As your question mentions, two other words that seem to be spelled with <gn> in Modern English for similar reasons are *sovereign* and *foreign.*

#### I don't think the use of "y" in Middle English spelling is very relevant to the use of "gn" in Modern English spelling

In Middle English, Y was used in many of the same ways as I. Apparently, Y was particularly likely to replace I when the vowel was "long", or when the letter was next to one of the ["minim" letters M or N](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250095/how-was-the-letter-u-written-in-old-english) (sequences like *im, in, mi, ni* are supposed to have been avoided in English writing at certain time periods because of the similarity of the strokes used to write these letters). (*[Complete Works Of Geoffrey Chaucer](https://books.google.com/books?id=rUR8CgAAQBAJ&pg=PP25)*, W.W. Skeat) So I think *feynen* and *feinen* or *alynen* and *alinen* are basically equivalent spellings.

Comment: Well done. For the record, Catalan orthography uses the digraph ‹ny› to represent [ɲ]. The weird thing is that they can have that sound in the coda, much as we can with [ŋ]. So Spanish *año* /ˈɑɳo/ is  Catalan *any* /ɑɳ/, and so *¿Cuántos años tienes?* in Spanish is just *Quants anys tens?* in Catalan, but *anys* is NOT pronounced like *anise*. It’s just /ɑɳs/. Catalan has so many digraphs that you’ll **never** figure out how to say it without a chart. Oh and they can have [ʎ] in the coda too, not just  [ɲ]; surname *Güell* is /ɡweʎ/. Spanish can’t have either [ʎ] or [ɲ] in the coda.

Comment: [Catalan digraph chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_orthography#Sound_to_spelling_correspondences). Example of weirdness: to make an affricated "g", instead of putting a coronal vowel after it, they put one before it as a digraph: ‹ig› is /tʃ/. Yes, **not** /dʒ/: for that you need ‹tg›. And although the Catalan digraph ‹ll› is /ʎ/ just like it is in (northern) Spanish, in Catalan they have a special [center-dot diacritic in ‹l·l› for the geminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_orthography#Punt_volat_(middot)), so /l.l/ or /lː/. Minimal pair: *ceŀla* [ˈsɛɫɫə] *cella* [ˈsɛʎə].

Comment: @tchrist: Thanks for the link and the example of another digraph for ɲ. Unrelatedly, but interestingly (in my opinion), I've read that Catalan can also have progressive assimilation of plural /s/, like in English, but in place of articulation rather than voicing: according to this [Linguistics SE post by ukemi](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27465), "nys" may be pronounced as [ɲʃ]

Comment: That’s absolutely correct. I was trying to spare you :) the palatalization effect of the coda sibilants, but it is in fact very common throughout Iberia. This same thing also occurs in most northern Spanish with their apical "s" /s/ > [s̺] which often sounds like [ʃ] to us, especially in the coda, and quite famously in all peninsular Portuguese codas — but not (at all so often) in Brazil. The Catalan *tens* (ES *tienes*, FR *tiens*) often sounds “just like” the (European) Portuguese one also spelled *tens* and pronounced [t̪ɛ̃ʒ]. There’s a lot of phonemic neutralization in these codas.

Comment: You write "As far as I know, none of the Romance languages retains either [ŋn] or [gn] in inherited/popular vocabulary." Well then, let me introduce you to Sardinian, the **most conservative** of living Romance languages. :) In [section 5.3.4 **gn** + vocale](http://www.sardegnacultura.it/documenti/7_108_20090205122432.pdf) on page 27, they write that the ‹gn› spelling is pronounced either /gn/ or /nni/, and give an example of the common word *campagna* being pronounced either "campagna" or "campànnia" (using their notation).

Comment: @tchrist: Is that document talking about pronunciation? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinian_language#cite_ref-226) seems to say that it's rather a case of both "gn" and "nni" or "nny" being used as spellings for the sound /ɲː/ in Sardinian. In any case, [gn] in the word "campagna" specifically could not be inherited since the Latin source has /ni/. If a pronunciation with [gn] exists in Sardinian, I think it would have to be a spelling pronunciation

Comment: Oh you might be right. I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 5):

From Etymology online:

- [align](https://www.etymonline.com/word/align): early 15c. The French spelling with *-g-* is unetymological, and *aline* was an early form in English.
- [arraign](https://www.etymonline.com/word/arraign): The unetymological *-g-* is a 16c. overcorrection based on *reign*, etc.
- [feign](https://www.etymonline.com/word/feign): A 17c. respelling. This word acquired a *-g-* in imitation of the French present participle stem *feign-* and the Latin verb.

Comment: I don’t know what “unetymological” means for the French there. The Middle French spelling was *alinher* because that’s how it was pronounced. Then they switched from using the *nh* digraph to represent the palatal nasal sound /ɲ/ to using the *gn* digraph in Modern French *aligner* to represent the exact same sound. That’s the same sound as in Modern French *oignon* meaning “onion” — which we’re now spelling *ni*. Would you call the *g* in French *oignon* “unetymological” just because Latin didn’t spell that sound that way in *union-*? I sure wouldn’t. Digraphs can’t be thought of in pieces.

Comment: @tchrist Hey! I didn't write Etymology Online, I'm just quoting it! Don't shoot the messenger! I think they're saying that there was no "g" in Middle English so it's unetymological in modern English, even though the "g" appears in Middle French. It's like "debt" being spelt with a "b" because the Latin word has a "b" too.

Comment: I actually thought a bit about *debt*,  and I don’t think it’s quite the same scenario. The story of *line* in English is complicated because per the OED it represents two words “ultimately of the same etymology” (read: a long-distance doublet) that have coalesced. Old English has *líne* from Old High German *lîna*, but Middle English not only had *line* from OE but also *ligne* from French that was ultimately derived from classical Latin *līnea*. And Old High German itself borrowed *linia* from popular Latin.

Comment: This is not a late update. Why is this not properly in the domain of the question? meta: It's not fair to earn up votes by answering **along with** the question. (I may be wrong, or I could have missed something, though.)

Comment: @Kris: self-answering is a valid way of posting on SE, which is why the site mechanics allow it (even immediately posting an answer at the same time as the question). Vote for questions and answers are separate things, just like for other posts

Comment: @Kris: It may be a less common use of the self-answer option, but that use has been explicitly treated as an OK use of self-answering for a long time: see the Meta post [Answering at the same time as asking ok?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3453) The site enables this practice by providing an "Answer your own question" checkbox that shows up when a question is being written.

Comment: @CJDennis no one is shooting the messager, only the message.

Comment: Yes re "feindre" having the stem "feign-", not just in the present participle but in the simple past, the imperfect, and the subjunctive.